# Symfony 2 Custom User Provider

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, shibboleth, symfony-security

I'm trying to get `ShibbolethBundle` (https://github.com/rmoreas/ShibbolethBundle) work. But stuck with creating a new user on login. I found out that the `userProvider` is not the correct class (the one that implements `ShibbolethUserProviderInterface` on here https://github.com/rmoreas/ShibbolethBundle/blob/master/Security/ShibbolethAuthProvider.php#L109

My custom provider is defined like this:

```
namespace Meot\FormBundle\Entity;
...
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements ShibbolethUserProviderInterface {
...
}
```

Security.xml

```yaml
....
security:
     providers:
         main_provider:
             entity: { class: Meot\FormBundle\Entity\User }

     firewalls:
         dev:
             pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
             security: false
         secured_area:
             pattern:    ^/
             shibboleth: ~
             logout:
                 path: /logout
                 target: /
                 success_handler: security.logout.handler.shibboleth
```

I found this cookbook (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) states

> To finish the implementation, the configuration of the security layer
> must be changed to tell Symfony to use the new custom entity provider
> instead of the generic Doctrine entity provider. It's trivial to
> achieve by removing the property field in the
> security.providers.administrators.entity section of the security.yml
> file.

Tried it, didn't work. The class of user provider is still `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider`.

I'm wondering by removing the property field, how Symfony is able to find my custom user provider?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It seems the DI container just create "EntityUserProvider" when specified "entity" in provider in security.xml. Then the AuthenticationProvider just call the methods in user provider. So I have to create a service for the user provider and specify ID in providers section in security.xml.

src/Meot/FormBundle/Resources/config/services.xml

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="custom_user_provider.class">Meot\FormBundle\Entity\UserRepository</parameter>
    <parameter key="custom_user_entity">Meot\FormBundle\Entity\User</parameter>
</parameters>
<services>
    <service id="custom_user_provider" class="%custom_user_provider.class%"
        factory-service="doctrine" factory-method="getRepository">
        <argument>%custom_user_entity%</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```